# RCP handler enabledwhen for multiple 'with' elements

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

How can I add multiple 'with' elements for enabledwhen? Here's my plugin.xml file

```
<handler
         class="com.myClass"
         commandId="com.myid">
         <enabledWhen>
           <with variable="menu.enablement">
                   <equals
                         value="true">
                   </equals>
            </with>
            <with variable="menu.request.state">
                   <equals
                         value="true">
                   </equals>
            </with>
         </enabledWhen>
</handler>
```

I want the enalbledWhen to be true only IF both the with elements evaluate to true but can I add two 'with' elements under the same enabledWhen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Use an `<and>` element as the common parent of both `<with>`s.

Comment: Can you please provide an example so that I can accept your answer? How can the <and> element be a common parent here?

Comment: Make `and` the only child of the `enabledWhen` element, and move your `with` elements into it.